# Need help with Database Access in Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, memory-leaks

I'm using an sqlite database in my app.  I have this dbhelper class in a services class like so.

```
    public class MushroomService {

        private int downloadprogress;
        private int databasesize;

        private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    }

    public MushroomService(Context context)
    {
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        downloadprogress = 0;
    }
```

The services class is a member of my application class like so:

```
public class fungifieldguideapplication extends Application {
    public MushroomService service = new MushroomService(this);
}
```

In my activity classes I access and keep this application as a local variable like so:

```
public class Cat_Genus extends Activity {
    fungifieldguideapplication appState;
    ListView list_Genus;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cat_genus);

        appState = ((fungifieldguideapplication)this.getApplication());

        Cursor cursor_genuslist = appState.service.GetGenusList(this);
        startManagingCursor(cursor_genuslist);
    }
}
```

and my service call looks like this:

```
public Cursor GetGenusList(Context context)
    {
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        Cursor cursor;
        try 
        {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.myDataBase;
            cursor = db.query(true, "Mushrooms", GenusListColumns, null, null, "Genus", null, "Genus ASC", null);
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            throw sqle;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

I've added these overrides in to try to get rid of my memory leaks.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        list_Genus.setAdapter(null);
        appState.service.CloseDB();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        appState.service.CloseDB();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        appState.service.OpenDB();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

But I can't get my memory leaks to stop.  Could somebody help me figure out how to rid myself of these memory leaks?  These leaks are of the type:

```
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175): Leak found
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175): java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/net.daleroy.fungifieldguide/databases/Mushrooms.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1695)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:739)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.data.DataBaseHelper.openDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:79)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.services.MushroomService.GetSpeciesListByGenus(MushroomService.java:113)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.activities.Cat_Species.onCreate(Cat_Species.java:46)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-27 17:38:44.613: ERROR/Database(26175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but perhaps its because you're not closing the database after interacting with it. When ever I'm doing db work on android I surround interactions in a Try { } Finally { } clause which closes connection on finally.

e.g

```
try{
//database stuff
} finally{
   db.close
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your program is terminating, because you are opening database twice

```
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context); // first here
    Cursor cursor;
    try 
    {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase(); //then here
```

you can probably remove 'myDbHelper.openDataBase();'

Comment: My program isn't terminating, its just causing memory leaks.  It doesn't do it every time either.

Comment: ok, so your program isn't terminating, but have you tested if 'myDbHelper.openDataBase();' is making memory leaks?