# error creating database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am displaying the database in a listview in android. i am displaying the listview in another activity. i am creating database in oncreate by just calling a class called "data" that extends sqliteopenhelper and passing the table but as soon as i launch the app the stack trace in DDMS is

```
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175): Leak found
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175): java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/com.cortes/databases/location.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1792)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:798)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:857)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:850)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.openOrCreateDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:539)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at com.cortes.Cortes.onCreate(Cortes.java:79)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
08-23 14:29:07.771: ERROR/Database(5175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 14:29:07.846: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2300): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd failed
08-23 14:29:07.846: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2300): wpa_driver_priv_driver_cmd failed
```

and my code is

```
db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("location.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
d = new data(this,Geo_Create_Table);
db=d.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: data is the name of new class which extends sqliteopenhelper

Comment: are you sharing the db between activities?

Comment: yes i m sharing the table geo_create_table between activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have enough reputation to put a comment yet >.< I'm gonna put this as an answer instead.

The stack trace contains this **SQLiteDatabase created and never closed** which leads me to believe that the database was never closed. I'm assuming that Android is griping about the three lines here
    db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("location.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
    d = new data(this,Geo_Create_Table);
    db=d.getWritableDatabase();
and since thats all that you provided I think you think the same. If I understand what this is trying to do, you are opening a locally stored Database `db` and then, I guess `d` is also referencing the same locally stored Database. MAYBE (not too sure) that is causing the memory leaks in your app, but one thing I do know is that you need to add the `db.close()` in there somewhere.

You could try the suggestion that this other user made by using a try {} finally{db.close()} 
[Need help with Database Access in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348238/need-help-with-database-access-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the the database connection before leaving an activity. The best way is to close on the `onPause()` callback and open on `onResume()`. This will ensure that the database connection is always in a valid state.

Relevant questions/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556930/sharing-sqlite-database-between-multiple-android-activities) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900740/android-sqlite-database-shared-between-activities).

The second link shows a strategy for sharing a database connection across activities by extending the `Application` class.